# android google map in fragment - can't remove

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, mapfragment, fragmentmanager

In my application I am trying to remove map fragment onDestroyView(). 
I am using support v4 library. I am sure it crashed when I try to remove map

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/countryLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/partnersLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mainFooterLayout">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map_n"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

but when I did this I have this error.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've searched a lot and couldn't fine anything useful.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: did it worked for you?

Comment: did you understand my answer? You cannot have fragment in XML completely. Wrapping it in FrameLayout does not change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove fragment that is "hardcoded" in XML layout file. You can only remove fragments you added from code yourself. So if you want your map really removed, you must first add it from code (so, i.e. use empty `<FrameLayout>` as you fragment container, initialize map fragment from code, add it to the said container. Then you will be able to remove it when you need so.

Answer (score 1):

try this (with "mapv2" is name of map_fragment in xml):

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (googleMap != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapv2))
                .commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to call super.onDestroyView() at the end